# Laravel 4 Queued Mailing throws error while directly sending works

Tags: php, email, laravel, queue

I have a Laravel 4 app where I need to send certain emails to users. I have no idea why but I keep getting this error on my test server (it does not happen on my local vagrant box)

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::getQueuedCallable() must
>   be of the type array, null given, called in
>   blablabla/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php
>   on line 238 and defined

I tried resetting everything: database, clean clone from git. None of these worked. I also cleared my browser cache and cookies out of desperation. I am using Sync queue. So it's not even an actual queue.

Mail::send works just fine. Mail::queue throws the error above.

I literally started to pull my hair out so any help will be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:

This is my **BookingMailer** class that extends Mailer class.

```
// partner bir arabanın rezervasyonuna onay verdiğinde müşteriye gönderilecek ödeme linki
public function sendPaymentLinkToCustomer($customer, $partner, $booking) {
    $view = 'emails.bookings.request_confirmed';

    $data = [
        'user' => $customer->full_name // string,
        'partner' => $partner->display_name // string,
        'reference' => $booking->reference // integer,
        'booking_id' => $booking->id // integer
    ];

    return $this->sendTo($customer, 'Booking Request Confirmed', $view, $data, true, true);
}
```

And this is my **Mailer** class that actually queues the mail.

```
public function sendTo($user, $subject, $view, $data = array(), $admin_copy=false, $send_as_pm=false)
{
            Mail::queue($view, $data, function ($message) use ($user, $view, $data, $subject, $admin_copy) {

                $message = $message->to($user->email)->replyTo(Config::get('mail.from.address'), Config::get('mail.from.name'))->subject($subject);

                return $message;
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this problem (at least in my case)

I was including the user first and last name to the mail. I was only showing the first letter of the last name, though. And I was using substr for a UTF-8 string, and that's why sometimes it returned problematic characters that get inside the data array and ultimately cause the queue to break.

When i used mb_substr instead of substr, my problem disappeared.

Phew, I thought I would never figure this one out on my own.